# How to connect database to data files in Azure Blob?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

[This resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/sql-server-data-files-in-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-ver15) states that a Azure SQL database may be attached to a database by using the following command:

```
WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',  
SECRET = '<your SAS key>'  
  
CREATE DATABASE testdb   
ON  
( NAME = testdb_dat,  
    FILENAME = 'https://testdb.blob.core.windows.net/data/TestData.mdf' )  
 LOG ON  
( NAME = testdb_log,  
    FILENAME =  'https://testdb.blob.core.windows.net/data/TestLog.ldf')
```

This results in Syntax Error near "ON". What is the issue here?

Comment: You're missing the `CREATE CREDENTIAL...` bit from the example.  The first statement should be `CREATE CREDENTIAL [...] WITH IDENTITY='...', SECRET='...';`

Comment: That part worked fine

Comment: What part worked fine?  You have a syntax error in your example.

Comment: The creation of the credential worked well, however for the record it needed to be changed from CREATE CREDENTIAL to CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL. The error is with the code that follows CREATE DATABASE testdb

Comment: You're mixing something up: that article is not about Azure SQL Database (which has [completely different `CREATE DATABASE` syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool#create-a-database) and doesn't use `FILENAME`), it's about storing files in Azure for **regular** SQL Server (on-prem or VM): *"It allows you to create a database in SQL Server running in on-premises or in a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure with a dedicated storage location for your data in Microsoft Azure Blob storage."*

Comment: Azure SQL has managed files. You don't know where they are and nor should you care. You just create a database. Are you trying to attach an existing db or create a new one? You can't populate an Azure SQL DB from a MDF file.

Answer (score 0):

To connect Azure SQL Database to Azure blob storage, you need to create an **external data source** with the database scoped credentials.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL BlobCred
WITH
IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'SAS token' ;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobStg
WITH
 ( LOCATION =‘https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net’,
CREDENTIAL = BlobCred,
TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE
) ;
```

Refer to official documents [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/ba-p/386133)  & [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated) for more details.